# Extract a DataTable with few conditions

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I have a DataTable as below:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
1001    Null     10
1001    W1        5
1001    W2        4
1002    Null      45
1002    W3        15
1002    W4        23
1003    W5        25
1003    W6        10
1003    W7        11
```

I want to extract another `DataTable` from the above, there's a condition that if the first value in `ColumnB` is Null wrt to the `ColumnA`, then extract that.

It means I need to check Null value in ColumnB and extract the corresponding distinct value from ColumnA.

The output should be

```
ColumnA
1001
1002
```

I wrote something as :

```
DataTable dt2 = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ColumnA");
```

but it gives me only the distinct values from ColumnA. It doesn't work as per my requirement.

I guess some LINQ query will work here, but I don't know LINQ.

Experts please help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ColumnB") == null)
                              .Select(x => x.Field<int>("ColumnA"));
```

**Edit:**

To fetch the count of those values in `ColumnA` which have `Null` in `ColumnB`:-

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ColumnA"))
               .Where(x => x.Any(z => z.Field<string>("ColumnB") == null))
               .Select(x => new { ColumnValue = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

Comment: Hi, I want to get the count of the distinct values too. What LINQ query should be written?

Comment: like 1001 3...1002 3 in a list or datatable? Can you help Mr. Rahul?

Comment: @Anurag - You can use GroupBy:- `var result = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ColumnA")).Select(x => new { ColumnValue = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });`

Comment: HI Rahul..Thanks for replying..I need to get the count of the distinct values in ColumnA for which I have Null in ColumnB. In above example, for 1001, I have Null in ColumnB. Hence I need to have 1001 and its count as 3 in a Datatable or a list. Will your above GroupBy query achieve it? Regards

Comment: HI Rahul..It totally works..but how will I extract the values from the new var result..I did .ToList() at the end of the new LINQ query. It gave me 2 records with ColumnValue as 1001 and Count as 3. I mean how to extract the individual values from this var?

Comment: You can access it in a `foreach` loop like this: `foreach(var item in result) { // item.ColumnValue , item.Count }`

Comment: Thanks Mr. Rahul..You have helped a lot..Really appreciate it. I am very poor in LINQ. Need to study and apply it. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without LINQ, just using a `DataView`:

```
var dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "ColumnB is null";   
var dt2 = dv.ToTable(true, "ColumnA");
```

Comment: But only if column B really contains `null`. It seems that here it's a string `Null`.

Comment: @t3chb0t Then try `"ColumnB is null or ColumnB = ''"` as the `RowFilter`.

Comment: @t3chb0t Sorry, misread your comment, if it is the string "Null" then you would set the filter to `"ColumnB is null or ColumnB = 'Null'"` (the first check may not be needed if it is never null.